# aspnet_regiis.exe -sn "" error

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have web setup project created by VS 2010, when i setup this project all works fine, but when i check "repair" option i get error during installation.

MSI log file

- Running process 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe' with parameters ' -norestart -sn ""' silently...
- Process Call Result Code: '0' Process Exit Code: '1'.
- The error indicates that IIS is in 32 bit mode, while this application is a 64 bit application and thus not compatible.
- Trying 32 bit version of 'aspnet_regiis.exe'...
- Reading registry value Path from key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0'...
- RESULT Path =
- Running process 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe' with parameters ' -norestart -sn ""' silently...
- Process Call Result Code: '0' Process Exit Code: '1'.
- The error indicates that IIS is in 64 bit mode, while this application is a 32 bit application and thus not compatible.

I couldnt uderstand why both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of aspnet_regiis not compatible to application? Whats the reason? Blank "path" param or something else? 
Running aspnet_regiis.exe with -sn option should update only specific application, not sub-applications, but what will occur if application isnt specified (path param is blank)? 
When i check "setup" not "repair" option, path param is set to my application and setup works fine, so maybe i have to change something in my setup project?

This error appears only on iis6, on iis7.5 this works fine, iis6 is set to 64-bit mode

Thanks